# $.datepicker not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I cannot coax the datetimepicker to work. Datepicker works fine. But the add-on has not worked after about 7 hours of attempts.

Firebug shows no 404's.

All jQuery libraries are included with the theme framework as well.

I tried replacing all instances of $.datepicker with jQuery.datepicker in the script. This made no difference.

I tried moving scripts above or below or combining them. The same error persists. I have examined several related answers in this forum and many, many others to no avail. I have reviewed jQuery literature but it does not address this specific problem..

My code is this. Just a couple of html inputs. Datepicker works fine.

```
   `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#datetime').datetimepicker();
});`
```

This segment of code works fine. Datetimepicker then hits the line

`$.datepicker.parseDateTime = function(dateFormat, timeFormat, dateTimeString, dateSettings, timeSettings) {`

$.datepicker not defined.

If you do not know the answer, perhaps there is a way for javascript/jQuery to produce more detailed information about its failures?

Comment: *Which* datetimepicker? If you're talking about jQuery UI, [it doesn't have one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/). It has a date picker, but not a date/time picker.

Comment: is datetimepicker already released with the JQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $.datepicker.parseDateTime = function(dateFormat, timeFormat, dateTimeString, dateSettings, timeSettings){};
});
```

Looks like you are trying to call the function before it gets loaded.  Jquery will go through each doc.ready function in order, so as long as this is after the initial load it should work.

Also, use chrome's built in develop tools for debugging purposes. Ctrl-shift-j on a PC will open them up, you can see the console messages to figure out whats going on.

heres a jsfiddle to show the working syntax  http://jsfiddle.net/XA79k/

Answer (score 0):

```
( function($$) {


$$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.datepicker.parseDateTime = function(dateFormat, timeFormat, dateTimeString, dateSettings, timeSettings) {
});

} ) ( jQuery );
```

I had similiar issues and had to do it this way since there was conflicts. And I tried jQuery.noConflict() aswell, but didnt work. Above code worked for me.

Comment: Those both seem to get past the initial problem. But a new error now occurs: function datetimepicker not found. The error happens here.                                                                                                                     `jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
 });`

Comment: No. Neither work. Back where I started. This is pure evil. 11 hours I wasted on absolutely nothing. I'm going to tell my client it will cost him $1,500 to have a field that says 'time' on his calendar. Of course, that's the idea isn't it. Javascript can't possibly be of any use to future generations. It's sterile, obsessive compulsive, and never works.

Comment: did you figure the issue out?  I updated the jsFiddle to show the working code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/XA79k/1/    You need to make sure you are including the jQuery Library, the jQueryUI library, the jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js, the CSS from the JqueryUI, AND the CSS from the datetimepicker.  Include them in that order and you shouldnt have a problem.