# JQuery UI doesnt work with Jquery 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-3.1.1.slim in a project and I cannot use jQuery UI to use the date picker. However the jQuery UI does not work with jquery-3.1.1 says datepicker is not defined error. How should I use jQuery UI elements with this version of jQuery without any conflict?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bundles/app/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('bundles/app/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is how they're loaded.

Comment: Its maybe you are using slim version...try to use full minified version

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on the official website [here](https://jqueryui.com/). JQuery UI of version 1.12.1 is responsible for jQuery 1.7 and above. Moreover jQuery was added to this version for testing porpose. Maybe you can try it with this version or refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599063/datepicker-not-defined).

Comment: I added the source to the question. Check again.

Comment: This is not an answer.submit this in comment.if you cant than remove this answer.